# If there's an optimal solution for a LP, does it have to be at one of the vertices?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I found this on Wikipedia.

> In the theory of linear programming, a basic feasible solution is a
> solution with a minimal set of non-zero variables. Geometrically, each
> BFS corresponds to a corner of the polyhedron of feasible solutions.
> If there exists an optimal solution, then there exists an optimal BFS.

Does this mean, in simple terms that optimal solution if it exists, has to be at one of the corners?

Comment: It means that if an optimal solution exists, then there also exists an optimal solution which is a vertex. But it may be different than the one you first thought of. In general the set of optimal solutions is some face of the polyhedron.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.  The result you found says that if there is an optimal solution then there is an optimal solution at a corner.  There could also be optimal solutions that occur at non-corners.  For a fairly trivial example, consider a linear program where the objective function is constant, so that every feasible solution is optimal.

The point here is that if you're looking for the value of an optimal solution you only need to look at the corners.  You may not find every place where the optimal solution is attained, but (if the problem has optimal solutions at all) you'll find the optimal value.